# Slack API request, limiting to 1 request per DAG failure (Airflow)

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, airflow, slack-api, directed-acyclic-graphs

Hello jr data engineer here!

For some strange reason my task_fail_slack_alert module is triggering the Slack API request a ridiculous amount of times, which is then showing up in our Slack channel that many times and is really annoying. My module should only run and show up in in Slack channel the same amount as the number of tasks that failed.

What am I missing?

```
import os
from airflow.models 
import Variable 
import json import requests

def get_channel_name():
  channel = '#airflow_alerts_local'
  env = Variable.get('env', None)
  if env == 'prod':
       channel = '#airflow_alerts'
  elif env == 'dev':
       channel = '#airflow_alerts_dev'
  return channel

def task_fail_slack_alert(context):
   webhook_url = os.environ.get('SLACK_URL')

   slack_data = {
         'channel': get_channel_name(),
         'text':
             """ :red_circle: Task Failed.
            *Task*: {task}
            *Dag*: {dag}
            *Execution Time*: {exec_date}
            *Log Url*: {log_url}
            """.format(
            task=context.get('task_instance').task_id,
            dag=context.get('task_instance').dag_id,
            ti=context.get('task_instance'),
            exec_date=context.get('execution_date'),
            log_url=context.get('task_instance').log_url,
          )}

    response = requests.post(webhook_url, data=json.dumps(slack_data),
           headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

    if response.status_code != 200: 
        raise ValueError( 'Request to slack returned an error %s, 
                    the response is:\n%s'(response.status_code, response.text))
    task_fail_slack_alert(context)
```

This is how I have it showing up in the arguments for each dag:

```
default_args = {
    'on_failure_callback': task_fail_slack_alert,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is recursive:

```
def task_fail_slack_alert(context):
    ......
    task_fail_slack_alert(context)
```

Remove the recursion as it's not needed.

Comment: I just want to make sure sure I understand correctly, are you saying I should remove the function call task_fail_slack_alert(context) from within my function? Like entirely?

Comment: @KristiLuna The `task_fail_slack_alert` is called by Airflow automatically when task is failed. So it executes the code you wrote in that function. After it posted a message to slack `requests.post` you also explicitly called `task_fail_slack_alert` again so the function is recursive and execute the whole code again and again.

Comment: @kristiluna what would leaving that call in achieve? and what would it mean to say, "partially", vs "entirely" remove the call? i don't understand...

Comment: @acushner I've removed the task_fail_slack_alert(context) and now I'm not getting any alerts

Comment: @Elad I've removed task_fail_slack_alert(context) but now I'm not getting any alerts in the Slack channel

Comment: @KristiLuna It's impossible to answer this because the code you provided is partial. Please post an example of your DAG so we can see the code. I'm also not clear why you use requests rather than `SlackWebhookOperator` but that's your choice

Comment: from where did you remove `task_fail_slack_alert`? you need to remove it from inside the `task_fail_slack_alert` function in case that wasn't clear.

Comment: @acushner yes! I removed it from inside the task_fail_slack_alert function, once I removed it, I didn't get any alerts, I was just 1 alert per dag failure

Comment: well what are you expecting? that's exactly what should happen. one alert per dag failure.

Comment: @acushner Yes! just one alert, I feel I'm stuck in the middle now. I'm either getting never-ending alerts because I have a recursive issue or I'm getting none when I remove the function call hah :-/

Comment: @KristiLuna as pointed out already. Your question has been answered you are now asking a new question so please open a new question with the full details and your DAG. We can't help you without seeing your DAG code and logs of the failed tasks and explain what you tried so far.